# How to create radio buttons dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have a problem in creating radio buttons dynamically, i have a text box and a button, i asked the user to input a value in the text field then i retrieve the text box value and use it to create a radio button when he press a button, i tried this code in javaScript but it doesn't create a radio button on clicking the specified button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function createRadioElement(value, checked) {
        var radioHtml = '<input type="radio" value="' + value + '"';
        if ( checked ) {
            radioHtml += ' checked="checked"';
        }
        radioHtml += '/>';

        var radioFragment = document.createElement('div');
        radioFragment.innerHTML = radioHtml;

        return radioFragment.firstChild;
    }

    $( '#admin' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){

        $( "#AddButton" ).bind( "click", function(event, ui) {

            var x=document.getElementById('option').value

            createRadioElement(x, checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

`

Comment: well it seems you know how to create an element since you create that div so why don't you create the input type=radio as well?

Comment: @Eslam I believe mVChr has the best answer (he beat me to it). I did rewrite your code a bit for legibility though: http://jsfiddle.net/t6m8M/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following for the creation of a radio input:

```
function createRadioElement(elem, value, checked) {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'radio';
        input.value = value;
        if (checked) {
            input.checked = 'checked';
        }

    elem.parentNode.insertBefore(input, elem.nextSibling);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JCaPm/).

---

**References:**

- [`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
- [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/Node.insertBefore).
- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode).

Comment: what's the parameter 'elem' represent?

Comment: The `elem` parameter is the one I'm using to define where, in the document, the radio input should be inserted. If you look at the linked [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JCaPm/) you'll see that I call the function with `createRadioElement(this,$('#t').val());` `elem` is `this` (the plain DOM node/HTMLElement), `value` is the value from the text input, and I don't know what `checked` is meant to be, but since you had it I left it there.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the problems as I can see them:

- In your `#AddButton` click function, you pass a variable `checked` which does not exist.
- You don't pass the element returned from `createRadioElement` to anything that will insert it into the DOM

I fixed those by basically changing your `#AddButton` click function to the following:

```
$("#AddButton").bind("click", function(event) {
    var x = document.getElementById('option').value,
        $ra = $('#RadioArea');

    $ra.html(createRadioElement(x, true));
});​
```

You'll probably want to change this so it appends the radio button to the end of whatever your `#RadioArea` element is instead of replacing the contents completely.

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8tAh4/)

Comment: i Tried it but unfortunately it doesn't work, although it works on jsFiddle!

Comment: now it works well,  but it didn't put the value retrieved from the text box behind the generated radio button, also it works for one time only, i want it to work every time the user clicks the button

Comment: i want to put the value retrieved from the text box behind the new generated radio button