# Store Values of Checkboxes in Array in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a dynamic array as such:

`var PartnerEmailList = [one@email.com, two@email.com, three@email.com];`

The following function creates a table that is displayed in a `showModalDialog` window.

```
function makeTableHTML() {
  var PartnerEmailList = [one@email.com, two@email.com, three@email.com];
  var result = "<table border=0>";
  result += "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name =" + PartnerEmailList[0] + " value =" + PartnerEmailList[0] + " checked></input></td>";
  result += "<td style=\"vertical-align:text-middle\">" + PartnerEmailList[0] + "</td></tr>";
  for(var i=1; i<PartnerEmailList.length; i++) {
    result += "<tr><td style=\"text-align:center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" unchecked></input></td>";
    result += "<td style=\"vertical-align:text-middle\">" + PartnerEmailList[i] + "</td></tr>";
  }
  result += "</table>";
  result += "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"action\" onclick=\"form_data()\">"
  result += "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Close\" onclick=\"google.script.host.close()\">"

  return result;
}
```

The user clicks a button within Google Sheets that runs the following script. This script pops up a ModalDialog window where the user can check which emails they want to send this product to.

```
function SelectEmails(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = makeTableHTML();
  var bccSend = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main_gen').getRange(2,2).getValue();
   if(bccSend === ''){
    //Call the HTML file and set the width and height
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(result)
      .setWidth(450)
      .setHeight(300);

  //Display the dialog
  var dialog = ui.showModalDialog(html, "Select the intended recipients of this briefing.");
  } 
}
```

I need to write a function that looks through all the checkboxes (they are all assigned a value within the html code) and stores the values of each one that is checked in an array. I will be calling this array in a different function to actually send out the email.

There may be a much better way to go about this, but this is what I have come up with so far. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hi hunter21188! In order to be able to solve your issue, you will need to create an html file in your project. Have you tried this option? If so, what is not working?

Comment: I have not created an html file because I am not sure how I would be able to pull in the array `PartnerEmailList` into that file. I'm sure that would be the way to go, but I am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: Where are you retrieving the `PartnerEmailList` array from then? Or is it hardcoded and you modify every time you want to have a change to it? @hunter21188

Comment: @ale13 I am retrieving it from a separate spreadsheet. The user enters the data, so it changes constantly. It is just stored in an array named `PartnerEmailList` that I can call whenever needed.

Comment: you might want to check these links: [1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html), [2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9574167). Are these of help to you? Can you post your progress regarding this? @hunter21188